# Does GTA IV require higher specs than GTA V?

Tags: technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-iv, framerate

I have a 940MX GPU laptop with an i7 processor and 16 GB RAM.

In this, *GTA V* runs fine (**30 FPS**) at 1024 × 768 resolution and low to medium settings.

So I thought since *GTA IV* is 4 years older than this, it would have a little less realistic graphics and be less resource-consuming.

But to my surprise, even at lower settings (all settings and details are at their lowest) and lower resolution, my ***GTA IV* struggles** to get even **18 FPS**. It is extremely slow as compared to *GTA V*.

It feels like I’m playing the latest graphics-rich game on max settings. It’s very weird.

**I was even more surprised** when I found some online YouTube videos about this game's (*GTA IV*) review, and they were getting 35 FPS on the same 940MX GPU laptop with an i5 processor. So I feel that something is wrong with my game.

So is this expected behavior, and is *GTA IV* actually "heavier" than *GTA V*? Or could it be an installation problem?

Comment: You could always try to see if there are any guides (like [this one](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1371539795); disclaimer: I haven't tried it, but it does mention things I know work for some other games) on changing config files or command-line arguments or mods that improve performance. It can't solve all performance problems, but it can solve a whole lot of them (not to mention all the other improvements you can get from making such changes).

Comment: Perhaps some of the bottleneck is in the CPU.  You didn't say what models of i7 vs. i5 you were talking about.  Although you'd guess that two laptops with 940MX GPUs would have similar generations of CPUs, so this wouldn't be a case of Skylake or Tiger Lake i5 vs. Sandybridge or Nehalem i7.  But could it be a ULV i7 vs. a medium-voltage i5?  Like 15 Watt Skylake i7 6500U (2c4t @ 2.5 / 3.0 GHz base / turbo, with 4MiB of L3 cache) vs. 45 Watt i5 7440HQ (4c4t @ 2.8GHz / 3.6 GHz two-core max turbo, 6 MiB of L3 cache).   (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylake_(microarchitecture)#Mobile_processors)

Comment: I assume with 16GiB of RAM that's two sticks, so you have dual-channel (twice the memory bandwidth of single channel).  Anyway, "i5" vs. "i7" is not a very useful way to say anything about how fast your CPU is.  Intel has been calling their CPUs i3..i7 since Nehalem in ~2009, and differences between generations can be more significant than the i5 to i7 difference within one generation.

Comment: @NotThatGuy unfortunately none of these made any effect on fps 

Answer (score 21, accepted):

GTA IV has a notoriously badly optimized PC port, so getting low FPS is to be expected (from personal experience: my current setup can run GTA V's singleplayer at constant 70+ frames with the graphics on a custom high-mid configuration, while running GTA IV at mid 40s-low 50s frames with FPS drops on the lowest graphics). That could also explain the difference in framerate despite the identical hardware.

Answer (score 13):

That is expected behavior and not due to an installation issue. *GTA IV*'s PC port is very unoptimized.<sup>[[1]](https://www.cinemablend.com/games/7-Great-Games-With-Truly-Horrible-PC-Version-90077.html) [[2]](https://videogamesuncovered.com/features/the-5-worst-pc-ports-of-all-time/) [[3]](https://www.gameskinny.com/yrq6t/forget-arkham-knight-here-are-the-10-worst-pc-ports-of-all-time)</sup> Its successor, *GTA V*, will usually have better performance on the same PC.

To improve GTA IV performance, see the [PC Gaming Wiki's GTA IV](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto_IV) article. I'm quoting some of its relevant performance-related text here:

> [**DXVK**](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/DXVK) — Can vastly improve the game's performance.
>
> [**Install DXVK**](https://www.reddit.com/r/pcgaming/comments/gsn6w8/dxvk_works_magic_on_gta_iv)
>
> 1. [Install DXVK](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/DXVK#Installation) to `<path-to-game>\GTAIV`.
> 2. Create a text file, name it `dxvk.conf`, and add `d3d9.maxFrameLatency = 1` to it to avoid or reduce occasional frame skipping and stuttering. [[source]](https://ant-sh.blogspot.com/2020/07/gta-4-stutter-choppiness-fix.html)
> 3. Add `d3d9.presentInterval = 1` to the file, which forces using DXVK's Vsync implementation. This may give less CPU overhead compared to the game's own Vsync implementation.
> 4. Add `d3d9.numBackBuffers = 3` to the file. This may further improve frametime stability while using Vsync.
>
> **Notes:**
>
> - The game may [wrongly detect the amount of VRAM available and only show 512 MB instead](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto_IV#VRAM_amount_is_wrongly_detected) while using DXVK.
> - The game may not use the desired resolution and refresh rate while using DXVK. Use the respective [commands](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto_IV#Launch_options) to remedy this. [[source]](https://github.com/doitsujin/dxvk/issues/1831)

> #### Large framerate drops on densely detailed parts of the city
>
> - Lower the view distance to 25 or lower. Anything higher may cause drops in performance when looking at the city's skyline or at densely
>   detailed areas (particularly Middle Park) for very little visual gain.
> - You may also increase your performance significantly while minimising pop-in and graphical glitches by setting the Detail
>   Distance between 10 and 40.
> - If you need very high framerates, it is recommended that you disable shadows as they are CPU-intensive and also reduce the Vehicle Density
>   to around 40 (33 is the console default if you want a "vanilla"
>   experience).
> - Keeping Vsync enabled (with the shadows disabled) may help maintain close to stable 60 FPS even on old Core 2 Quad CPUs.
> - Alternatively, you can also try out disabling Clip Capture in the "Game" option in main menu and setting `-mispecaudio` which can unload
>   the CPU to some extent depending on your specs and `-noprecache` in some
>   scenarios and `-disableimposters` excluding flying.

> `-minspecaudio`: forces lower quality audio - good for lower-end processors (while it doesn't decrease the definition of the audio, some extra audio details were removed, therefore reducing CPU load).

> #### Game will load with minimal graphics settings and won't let you change them
>
> - For video cards that have more than 2 GB or VRAM the game will run but won't let you change the graphics settings to anything better. In
>   order to force the game to allow the changes, load the game's
>   executable with this extra parameter: `-norestrictions.`
> - Bypass graphics restrictions on Steam version
>
> 1. Open your Steam library.
> 2. Right-click on 'Grand Theft Auto IV' and select 'Properties'.
> 3. Press the `Set Launch Options...` button.
> 4. Enter `-norestrictions` into the text field, press 'OK'.
> 5. Start the game.
>
> - Bypass graphics restrictions on other versions
>
> 1. Go to ''.
> 2. Create a new text file in this folder and name it `commandline.txt`.
> 3. Open it and add the string `-norestrictions` to it.
> 4. Save the file.
> 5. Start the game.

If on Windows 10:

> #### Disable fullscreen optimization
>
> - Go to the installation folder.
> - Right click on `GTAIV.exe` and enter its properties screen.
> - Under the compatibility tab, tick 'Disable fullscreen optimisations' and click 'OK'.

There are also other [performance-improving software or mods](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto_IV#Modifications) listed on the same PC Gaming Wiki article that you might want to try.